# Removing/Inserting UI element in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having an annoying problem at the moment, I have created an observeEvent({}) to add/remove some UI elements based on alternating clicks of a button, however after the element is added, a subsequent click of the button fails to remove it.

```
    server <- function(input, output,session) {
global <- reactiveValues(add.A = FALSE)
 observeEvent(input$add.A,{
global$add.A = !global$add.A
if(global$add.A){
  insertUI(
  selector = "#heading",
  where = "afterEnd",

  ui =  div(id = "alleles.A",
          fluidRow(
            column(width=6,
              div(div(class="ddown",uiOutput("Recipient.HLA.A.1")),div(class="ddown",uiOutput("Recipient.HLA.A.2")))
            ),
            column(width=6,
              div(div(class="ddown",uiOutput("Donor.HLA.A.1")),div(class="ddown",uiOutput("Donor.HLA.A.2")))
          )
         )
       )
     )
    }else{
      removeUI(selector = "#alleles.A")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: if you use `removeUI("div:has(> #alleles.A)")` does it work as expected?

Comment: No I tried that as well. What is weird is I can  remove the heading UI element if I get put #heading instead of #alleles.A

Comment: Try not using the dot in the id of the html element it think this confuses the selection in the dom, something like look for element id of alleles and class A. I have tried with alleles.A and it does not work if you use only alleles it works.

Comment: Valter I think you go it. I changed to 'alleles_A' and it works. Thank you!